# How to remap Ctrl-Alt-Tab to Ctrl

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

Long story short: I have MX master 2s mouse whose thumb button sends `<ctrl><alt><tab>`.

I want to remap the thumb button to `<ctrl>` but that does not seem to be possible because there are no supported software for linux.

Hence I would like to do the next best thing, which is to try to remap `<ctrl><alt><tab>` to `<ctrl>` and hope it works.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you are trying to circumvent the effects of what **"ctrl+alt+tab"** does when you hit that mouse button (maybe frequently by accident???)...

You could, alternatively, disable what **"ctrl+alt+tab"** does and/or assign it to a different key sequence (which I believe is change panels?)

From the Applications menu or the panel, under **Settings --> Keyboard Shortcuts**

There you can disable the function  it executes... or reassign it.

FYI (for others),
On MATE Desktop, that option doesn't show up in the GUI... So on the command line I had to:

`gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-windows-all '<Control><Alt>9'`

I just picked "9" because I knew it was harmless key sequence I would never type.

On Unity I believe the equivalent would be:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels "['<Control><Alt>9']"`